# Small percentage of users receive page cannot be displayed - Website hosted on Windows server 2016

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2016, iis-10

A very small percentage of users out of thousands are unable to display my https website on any browser or any computer inside their network. These problems did not arise until after upgrading approximately 3 months ago from Windows server 2008 to Windows server 2016.

For one particular customer the culprit happen to be Vipre antivirus because when they white listed my site it worked.

I have 2 Windows 2016 machines and the same customers can't access either. There's nothing special about these websites or how they are set up. I have kept the default ssl crypto negotation settings on Windows Server 2016.

Is there some setting on Windows server 2016 that has changed from 2008 that I'm not aware of or could it be that Windows 2016 is still relatively new and security providers have not seen enough issues to remedy them?

[image: Bindings]

[image: Application Pool]

Comment: Have a user that can't access the site, try it in Chrome or Firefox. IE and Edge have "Friendly Error Messages" turned on, which means they hide the actual problem.  Chrome or Firefox should give you more information.

Comment: You need to use tools like Fiddler or Wireshark to analyze at TCP/SSL connection level. Before such details are revealed, it is impossible to move on.